# Erlang/OTP - Timing Applications

Tags: erlang, performance, timing

I am interested in bench-marking different parts of my program for speed.  I having tried using `info(statistics)` and `erlang:now()`

I need to know down to the microsecond what the average speed is. I don't know why I am having trouble with a script I wrote.

It should be able to start anywhere and end anywhere. I ran into a problem when I tried starting it on a process that may be running up to four times in parallel.

Is there anyone who already has a solution to this issue?

EDIT:

Willing to give a bounty if someone can provide a script to do it. It *needs* to spawn though multiple process'.  I cannot accept a function like timer.. at least in the implementations I have seen.  IT only traverses one process and even then some major editing is necessary for a full test of a full program.  Hope I made it clear enough.

Comment: There are a couple of ungivens: Is this a production system? `eprof` and *especially* `fprof` incur a performance hit when running. Both can follow newly-spawned-proceses. You may want to measure something else like network round-trips and so on however! The easiest way is probably to inject a `timer:tc` call around the function to be measured. Alternatively, take the `erlang:now()` and ship it off to another process which can then do the measurement work.

Comment: you've got your eprof script (or walkthrough) lower on the page :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here's how to use eprof, likely the easiest solution for you:

First you need to start it, like most applications out there:

```
23> eprof:start().
{ok,<0.95.0>}
```

Eprof supports two profiling mode. You can call it and ask to profile a certain function, but we can't use that because other processes will mess everything up. We need to manually start it profiling and tell it when to stop (this is why you won't have an easy script, by the way).

```
24> eprof:start_profiling([self()]).
profiling
```

This tells eprof to profile everything that will be run and spawned from the shell. New processes will be included here. I will run some arbitrary multiprocessing function I have, which spawns about 4 processes communicating with each other for a few seconds:

```
25> trade_calls:main_ab().
Spawned Carl: <0.99.0>
Spawned Jim: <0.101.0>
<0.100.0>
Jim: asking user <0.99.0> for a trade
Carl: <0.101.0> asked for a trade negotiation
Carl: accepting negotiation
Jim: starting negotiation
... <snip> ...
```

We can now tell eprof to stop profiling once the function is done running.

```
26> eprof:stop_profiling().
profiling_stopped
```

And we want the logs. Eprof will print them to screen by default. You can ask it to also log to a file with `eprof:log(File)`. Then you can tell it to analyze the results. We tell it to collapse the run time from all processes into a single table with the option `total` (see the [manual](http://erldocs.com/R14B/tools/eprof.html?i=5&search=eprof#analyze/1) for more options):

```
27> eprof:analyze(total).           
FUNCTION                                  CALLS      %  TIME  [uS / CALLS]
--------                                  -----    ---  ----  [----------]
io:o_request/3                               46   0.00     0  [      0.00]
io:columns/0                                  2   0.00     0  [      0.00]
io:columns/1                                  2   0.00     0  [      0.00]
io:format/1                                   4   0.00     0  [      0.00]
io:format/2                                  46   0.00     0  [      0.00]
io:request/2                                 48   0.00     0  [      0.00]
...
erlang:atom_to_list/1                         5   0.00     0  [      0.00]
io:format/3                                  46  16.67  1000  [     21.74]
erl_eval:bindings/1                           4  16.67  1000  [    250.00]
dict:store_bkt_val/3                        400  16.67  1000  [      2.50]
dict:store/3                                114  50.00  3000  [     26.32]
```

And you can see that most of the time (50%) is spent in dict:store/3. 16.67% is taken in outputting the result, another 16.67% is taken by erl_eval (this is why you get by running short functions in the shell -- parsing them becomes longer than running them).

You can then start going from there. That's the basics of profiling run times with Erlang. Handle with care, eprof can be quite a load on a production system or for functions that run for too long. Especially on a production system.

Comment: Nice Work man, tried it out, looks nice..  A question:  Why do some process' say 0 calls in my prog?  I know it had to have been called in order to have some other funs such as lists:flatten be called.  Is this something obvious? Or a little more esoteric to my prog.

Comment: I couldn't say without the code -- I don't remember seeing it in my own code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [eprof or fprof](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/profiling.html).

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to do this is with timer:tc. [Here](http://www.trapexit.org/Measuring_Function_Execution_Time) is a good explanation.

Comment: I need it to run across process' not just test one.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you this tool: https://github.com/virtan/eep

You will get something like this https://raw.github.com/virtan/eep/master/doc/sshot1.png as a result.

Step by step instruction for profiling all processes on running system:

On target system:

```
1> eep:start_file_tracing("file_name"), timer:sleep(20000), eep:stop_tracing().
$ scp -C $PWD/file_name.trace desktop:
```

On desktop:

```
1> eep:convert_tracing("file_name").
$ kcachegrind callgrind.out.file_name
```